# How to remove an element in array with length 1 so theres no gap

Tags: solidity

Guys how should i remove and element with filling the gap if the array contains only the element that im deleting??And because of that removing an element with shifting doesnt work. What  other ways could i use to delete an element filling the gap??

Solution:

```
uint[] public arr;

function modifyArray(uint[] memory _arr) public {
  arr=_arr;
}

function remove(uint num) public {
  
  
    for(uint i=0;i < arr.length; i++){
      
      if(arr.length ==1 || i+1 == arr.length) {
        arr.pop();
      }

       else {
         arr[i] = arr[i +1];
         arr.pop();
       }

    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have four options:
Create a new array and assign the parts of old array in the order you want

Use temp variables and reassign the elements of you array

Push new elements to the end your array via *_array.push(element)*

Pop the last element of your array until you get the achieved result via *_array.pop(element)* and the push the part you want after that

Or a combination of these.

Comment: ok ill figure out whats the best way thanks!

Comment: wait i could just have an if statement that check if the length is 1 then just do pop() but if its more then replace the gap with the last element right?? Or the pop() is going to leave the 0x0000000000000 ??

Comment: Could you give me the example? *pop* frees the memory on the EVM but you no longer can access that memory location. *pop* on an array of length 1 results in an empty array (length 0).

Comment: ok i added an example i think it shoud work

Comment: From the code you provided this would be the same effect: `function remove() public { require(arr.length==1); arr.pop();}`

Comment: You would make this an *if* statement if you didn't want the transaction to revert after trying this code somewhere else in you code